# CloudFormation Key Value pair in Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am fairly new to AWS so question I am asking here may sound like very basic. I am trying to define cloudformation template and I have requirement that I need to tag each resources I create.

I can easily create resources and apply tags using following

```
Resources:
  ResourceName1:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: 'ResourceName1'
      Type: String
      Value: 'Value'
      Tags:
        a: 'some value A'
        b: 'some value B'
        c: 'some value C'
  ResourceName2:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: 'ResourceName2'
      Type: String
      Value: 'Value'
      Tags:
        a: 'some value A'
        b: 'some value B'
        c: 'some value C'
```

Here if I create multiple resources tags will be repeated and If I need to make change to tag value I have to change that many time for each resources, So I was thinking if something like below is possible where I can externalize Tags.

```
Mappings:
  EnvVariables:
    tags:
    [ a: 'some value A'
      b: 'some value B'
      c: 'some value C'
    ]

Resources:
  ResourceName1:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: 'ResourceName1'
      Type: String
      Value: 'Value'
      Tags:
        !FindInMap [EnvVariables, tags]
  ResourceName2:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: 'ResourceName2'
      Type: String
      Value: 'Value'
      Tags:
        !FindInMap [EnvVariables, tags]
```

Either this or if there is any other way to externalize Tags in one place and refere to it from Resources it would make doing changes to tag easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse list of CloudFormation tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425305/reuse-list-of-cloudformation-tags)

Answer (score 1):

When you create CloudFormation stacks, you can associate tags with each resource, that supports tags, in the stack by defining tags on the Stack options page or using the --tags flag from the CLI/API.a)b)

a) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html

b) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

I hope this helps